# 2x2 difference table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to make a table like this in pandas:

[image: difference table]

I started with a pivot table like this:

```
# Create data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'treatment': [True, False, True, False],
  'young': [True, True, False, False],
  'val': [10, 5, 8, 12]
})
# Pivot.
df.pivot_table('val', 'treatment', 'young')
# young     False  True
# treatment     
# False        12     5
# True          8    10
```

But had trouble adding a difference row and column. Is there a direct way to add differences as margins to pivot tables?

Comment: would you like show as some data sample

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular do not post pictures. Post actual data.

Comment: Added a reproducible example, with columns that correspond to the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diff` can help here:

```
# Save the pivot table as we'll use it later.
p = df.pivot_table('val', 'treatment', 'young')
# Add the diff row.
p.loc['diff'] = p.diff().iloc[1]
# Add the diff column.
p['diff'] = p.diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1]
p
# young      False  True    diff
# treatment         
# False       12.0   5.0    -7.0
# True         8.0  10.0     2.0
# diff        -4.0   5.0     9.0
```